# TFF: Customizing the model implementation

Tags: google-colaboratory

Please can anyone explain to me this part of tuto:
here is the link https://www.tensorflow.org/federated/tutorials/federated_learning_for_image_classification
Part:
Customizing the model implementation
Keras is the recommended high-level model API for TensorFlow, and we encourage using Keras models (via tff.learning.from_keras_model or tff.learning.from_compiled_keras_model) in TFF whenever possible.

However, tff.learning provides a lower-level model interface, tff.learning.Model, that exposes the minimal functionality necessary for using a model for federated learning. Directly implementing this interface (possibly still using building blocks like tf.keras.layers) allows for maximum customization without modifying the internals of the federated learning algorithms.

So let's do it all over again from scratch.

Defining model variables, forward pass, and metrics
The first step is to identify the TensorFlow variables we're going to work with. In order to make the following code more legible, let's define a data structure to represent the entire set. This will include variables such as weights and bias that we will train, as well as variables that will hold various cumulative statistics and counters we will update during training, such as loss_sum, accuracy_sum, and num_examples.

MnistVariables = collections.namedtuple(
    'MnistVariables', 'weights bias num_examples loss_sum accuracy_sum')

Answer (score 0):

Roughly analogous to the multiple paths Keras exposes to create a Keras model, TFF exposes multiple distinct ways of creating a [`tff.learning.Model`](https://www.tensorflow.org/federated/api_docs/python/tff/learning/Model). One of them is through the constructor functions, `tff.learning.from_keras_model` or `tff.learning.from_compiled_keras_model`, but each of these functions constructs and returns an instance of the abstract base class `tff.learning.Model`; the purpose of this section of the tutorial is to show that it is possible to instead *directly* construct such an instance by implementing the appropriate methods in the abstract interface.

If it is the `collections.namedtuple` `MnistVariables` you are asking about, it is simply a data container class introduced for convenience, to help group the [`tf.Variables`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/Variable) which will roughly be used by the TFF runtime to track state during training. One important thing to note from the `tff.learning.Model` documentation, evidenced by this tutorial, is the line:

> All `tf.Variables` should be introduced in `__init__`

If you are familiar with TensorFlow Variables, you will understand that controlling their instantiation is quite important.

Comment: Hi Ayness, could you direct me to which point you'd like clarification on?

Comment: Hello Keith, please i want to know version of tensorflow , keras and Tensorflow federated that requires for this tutorial of tensorflow federated for image classification

Comment: The version the tutorial is written against is located in the tutorial's URL, e.g. the one currently linked from tensorflow.org is `0.11`. TFF depends on nightly TensorFlow, due to our development environment, as well as a particular version of tensorflow-addons, due to periodic breakage in that package. Running `!pip freeze` after installing TFF in a fresh colab and verifying the cells work shows TFF 0.11 should work with TF nightly on Dec 29 (IE today), and the rest of the dependencies should work themselves out no problem (no explicit Keras dep required)

Comment: Hello Keith, thank you very much for your help, can you tell me the tutorial was implemented with tensorflow or keras? (first part of tutorial, when the model was created)

Comment: I believe these models are generally written using the `tf.keras` API; I am not sure about the interop between this library and "pure" Keras. But `tf.keras` is IIUC a separate implementation of the Keras API, internal to TensorFlow, so the semantics should be "the same".

Comment: yes i think so, too, but the second part of tutorial, that I just wrote it down ,( with tff.learning) was implemented differently , So it's better to use the first or the second one ? knowing that I want to implement a code with tensorflow federated

Comment: It depends what you want, but I would recommend just writing Keras (`tf.keras`, that is)--the part of the code you're looking at is really just specifying the local computation. Writing Keras and using `tff.learning.from_keras_model` or `from_compiled_keras_model` should give you all the expressivity you are looking for--the other codepath is generally for those who would rather not write Keras

Comment: I would like to know please, How determinate number of rounds to obtain optimal accuracy ? is there any rule ?